# Why does a Qlik Sense Load Script with MySQL query hang when a BIT data type column is added?

Tags: mysql, bit, qliksense

I'm running a very simple Qlik Sense script which connects to MySQL and returns a resultset. Everything runs OK until a bit datatype column is added. Then the Load Script just keeps on 'loading'. It will stay like that for hours on end. When I remove the BIT column from the column list in the SELECT statement, the script runs in a few seconds. Here is the script that works:

```
LIB CONNECT TO 'MySQL_.......';

First 5
LOAD col1,
     col2,
     col3;

[my_table]:
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3;
FROM `db_name`.`table_name`;
```

And, after adding the column of BIT data type, the script hangs:

```
LIB CONNECT TO 'MySQL_.......';

First 5
LOAD col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     bitCol;

[my_table]:
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       bitCol;
FROM `db_name`.`table_name`;
```

Note: object names changed for privacy.

I looked up documentation on Qlik and it there is nothing specifically that says anything about BIT data type nuances. I'm baffled and any direction appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that encounters this issue. The Qlik MySQL connector was causing the issue. I setup a system ODBC data source to the MySQL instance and used a Qlik ODBC connection instead and it worked right away.